# Mounting s3 to wowza ec2: Can't 'make' s3fs-fuse

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, wowza

I'm trying to mount S3 bucket to a wowza ec2 instance bought from amazon marketplace, following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/tensult/aws-how-to-mount-s3-bucket-using-iam-role-on-ec2-linux-instance-ad2afd4513ef) or any other. I can't `make`

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-46-59 s3fs-fuse]$ make
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/ec2-user/s3fs-fuse'
Making all in src
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/ec2-user/s3fs-fuse/src'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/ec2-user/s3fs-fuse/src'
Making all in test
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/ec2-user/s3fs-fuse/test'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/ec2-user/s3fs-fuse/test'
Making all in doc
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/ec2-user/s3fs-fuse/doc'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/ec2-user/s3fs-fuse/doc'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/ec2-user/s3fs-fuse'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/ec2-user/s3fs-fuse'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ec2-user/s3fs-fuse'
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-46-59 s3fs-fuse]$ sudo make install
Making install in src
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/ec2-user/s3fs-fuse/src'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/ec2-user/s3fs-fuse/src'
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/bin'
  /usr/bin/install -c s3fs '/usr/bin'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/ec2-user/s3fs-fuse/src'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ec2-user/s3fs-fuse/src'
Making install in test
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/ec2-user/s3fs-fuse/test'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/ec2-user/s3fs-fuse/test'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/ec2-user/s3fs-fuse/test'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ec2-user/s3fs-fuse/test'
Making install in doc
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/ec2-user/s3fs-fuse/doc'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/ec2-user/s3fs-fuse/doc'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/share/man/man1'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 man/s3fs.1 '/usr/share/man/man1'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/ec2-user/s3fs-fuse/doc'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ec2-user/s3fs-fuse/doc'
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/ec2-user/s3fs-fuse'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/ec2-user/s3fs-fuse'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/ec2-user/s3fs-fuse'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ec2-user/s3fs-fuse'
```

Comment: FWIW: Wowza Streaming Engine has a mediacache feature that can use S3: https://www.wowza.com/docs/how-to-scale-video-on-demand-streaming-with-media-cache#mediacacheconf_sourcesadds3.  Not sure if that meets your needs...

Comment: This looks like make and make install both succeeded?  But agreed that yum install s3fs is a better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by installing `s3fs-fuse` using yum and

```
sudo s3fs bucketFolder /var/www/html/Example-folder/ -o passwd_file=/root/.passwd-s3fs -o allow_other,umask=277,uid=500,gid=500,use_cache=/root/cache
```

​
You get the guid and uid by running `id` command as a regular user in the terminal. Create a cache folder if you intend on using cache. And the other options are needed to give the regular user access to the mounted partition.

The folder you want to mount should be empty ideally, otherwise, you get a warning